# UTM grid layer in Garmin GPS

Tags: vector-grid, utm, garmin

I would like to ask if someone could point me in the right direction.

I need a UTM grid (1x1km) layer in Garmin handheld GPS, so the UTM grid would show on top of the map. The grid layer should be on/off switchable in map selection in Garmin. In order to be on/off switchable, it would have to be .img format.

Any ideas on what SW to use to generate the UTM grid and what format so it could be converted into .img? Or ideály, saved in .img right away. The UTM grid does not have to be for the whole world, just one country (33/34 U).

Model: Garmin Alpha 100/200i

Comment: Which Garmin handheld GPS? (Some models do this differently)

Comment: Garmin Alpha 100/200i.

Answer (score 0):

Garmin Alpha 100/200i supports kml/kmz

You can download UTM 33/34 U from

> https://www.valleyair.org/busind/pto/Resources/Mapping%20Tools/KML%20Tools/UTM%20Zones.kmz

Comment: If I get it right, this only shows UTM Zones. I need a UTM 1x1km grid. Perhaps I should have mentioned this. I will edit the question and add it there.

Answer (score 0):

.img files are in a Garmin proprietary format. The format has been reverse-engineered and there are tools that will allow you to generate your own .img files, though it is not for the faint of heart. The best explanation I've found is [here](https://www.gpsfiledepot.com/tutorials/how-to-create-garmin-topo-maps/). This covers how to generate a topo map; the grid you want to produce should be simpler, though the key step of converting to .img remains the same.